# Convert plaintext script into hex-encoded script in python

Tags: transactions, script, python, op-return

I'm creating a program (for an altcoin I'm developing) that should make it easy to create OP_RETURN transactions. Currently I'm having some trouble with actually creating the script pythonically (I can do it by hand but no idea how to program it).

As an example, the program takes an OP_RETURN script (eg. 6a4c0a0102030405060708090a) and creates a transaction with that script, by itself. However, currently you need to input the actual hex script instead of the string you want to send to the blockchain.

My question is - what's the best way to take a string/int and convert it into a transaction-friendly hex-encoded script? For example:

```
String: OP_RETURN 12345678910
Output: 6a4c0a0102030405060708090a
```

Thanks a bunch to anyone who helps. I'll you all some bitcoin if you manage to find a good solution.

Comment: This is more of a programming question than a bitcoin-specific question

Comment: All the bitcoin-related information you need is in the spec: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script  Other than that, you will need to learn about converting values to binary/hex in python, which is more of a general programming question based asked on the main Stack Overflow site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone here who needs this answer too: my friend created a simple program in Python and c++ to do this exact thing. You can download it on [here](https://github.com/chancoin-core/returnify).

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading [the specification](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script). Your hex string has to start with `6a` [OP_RETURN opcode] followed by `4c` [OP_PUSHDATA1] followed by a one-byte number indicating the size (in bytes) of the following data. You have 10 bytes, so this `0a`. Then come your actual data, and here I think you made a mistake. In any case, `0102030405060708090a` (in your by-hand example) is neither the hex encoding of the string `"12345678910"` nor of the integer `12345678910`. Look at this python snippets:

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> hex(12345678910)
'0x2dfdc1c3e'

>>> hexlify("12345678910".encode()).decode()
'3132333435363738393130'
```

So I guess you need to clarify what your data represent and how you want it encoded...